# FullSimplify doesn't simplify enough

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In `12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)`, writing:

```
num = 7 (3764 + 3673 Sqrt[2]) x^4 - 12 (19302 + 10727 Sqrt[2]) x^3 y + 756 (-44 + 31 Sqrt[2]) x^2 y^2 + 864 (37 + 51 Sqrt[2]) x y^3 - 5184 (2 + Sqrt[2]) y^4;
den = ((7 + 10 Sqrt[2]) x - 6 y) ((9 + 32 Sqrt[2]) x + 12 (1 + Sqrt[2]) y);
FullSimplify[num/den^2]
FullSimplify[num/den]/den
```

I get:

[image]

where it's evident that the second expression is more compact than the first. Is there a way to get it automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
num=7 (3764+3673 √2) x^4-12 (19302+10727 √2) x^3 y+756 (-44+31 √2) x^2 y^2+864 (37+51 √2) x y^3-5184 (2+√2) y^4;
den=((7+10 √2) x-6 y) ((9+32 √2) x+12 (1+√2) y);

MinimalBy[z /. Simplify@First@Solve[Reduce[z==num/den^2, #], z, Method->Rational] & /@
 {x, y}, LeafCount]
```

> $\frac{\left(6-5 \sqrt{2}\right) x-12 \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) y}{\left(23 \sqrt{2}-55\right) x-12 y}$

Another way

```
factor = Factor[num/den^2, Extension -> Automatic]
With[{expr = (a x + b y)/(c x + d y)}, 
  expr /. RootReduce@SolveAlways[factor == expr, {x, y}]] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Cool +1. Any idea how to reduce the coefficients I got?  Simplifying the difference of our answers yields zero, but gosh my numbers are huge.

Comment: Btw v. 11.3 gives a longer result.

Answer (score 2):

By default `FullSimplify` and `Simplify` avoid large numbers through the default complexity function.  Use `LeafCount` instead if you don’t mind the large numbers:

```
FullSimplify[num/den^2, ComplexityFunction->LeafCount]
(*
  (6432772386615749160*x + 4548621517377519337*Sqrt[2]*x - 42218157353358559728*y - 
    29852856498186887412*Sqrt[2]*y) /
    (134971395315929658167*x + 
     95439426336007826330*Sqrt[2]*x + 72071013851545447140*y + 
     50961935174866167276*Sqrt[2]*y)
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

This way it simlifies even more (or less)

```
num/den^2 // Apart // FullSimplify // Factor // FullSimplify
```

$$
\frac{7 \left(124944256776+87864579823 \sqrt{2}\right) x-12 \left(476402576068+337753093375 \sqrt{2}\right) y}{\left(691401+441484 \sqrt{2}\right)
   \left(\left(13669487+10004398 \sqrt{2}\right) x+12 \left(616179+439573 \sqrt{2}\right) y\right)}
$$